# Confusion matrix from caret R package

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I noticed that the definition of the confusion matrix looks quite weird in caret R package. To show this, I use the example from the package:

```
library(caret)
    lvs <- c("normal", "abnormal")
    truth <- factor(rep(lvs, times = c(86, 258)),
                    levels = rev(lvs))
    pred <- factor(
        c(
            rep(lvs, times = c(54, 32)),
            rep(lvs, times = c(27, 231))),
        levels = rev(lvs))


    confusionMatrix(pred, truth)


Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction abnormal normal
  abnormal      231     32
  normal         27     54

               Accuracy : 0.8285          
                 95% CI : (0.7844, 0.8668)
    No Information Rate : 0.75            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0003097       

                  Kappa : 0.5336          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.6025370       

            Sensitivity : 0.8953          
            Specificity : 0.6279          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8783          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.6667          
             Prevalence : 0.7500          
         Detection Rate : 0.6715          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.7645          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7616          

       'Positive' Class : abnormal
```

From the confusion matrix: Sensitivity = `231/(231+27)= 0.8953488` and specificity = `54/(54+32)=0.627907`, however, I believe that the sensitivity must be `231/(231+32)=0.878327` and specificity `= 54/(54+27)=0.666667`.

Can someone explains?

Comment: The output is correct. For instance, sensitivity is equal to the correct anomaly detection (true positives) divided by everyone in the sample with the anomaly (column 1), which is equal to 231/(231 + 27) = 0.8953.

Comment: sensitivity=positive given positive. specificity=negative given negative

Comment: Well, my understanding is that from the (231+32) abnormal prediction, 231 is predicted correctly and 32 misclassified. Then the sensitivity is 231/(231+32). Is not that right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

Comment: @Patrik_P thanks. Please can you justify my comment above?

Comment: you calculated precision and NPV